# MVC Output Caching Expire After 1 Min

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outputcache, output-caching

I've set an output cache for an Action as set out below. The cache duration is set for 3600 seconds, but the cache is refreshed every minute. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
        [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Any)]
        public ActionResult index()
        {
            var obj = db.tblAdvertisings.GroupBy(c => c.tblCategoryDetail.tblCategory.Category_Information).
                 OrderByDescending(c => c.Count()).
                 Select(c => new AdsCategory
                 {
                     count = c.Count(),
                     category = c.Key,
                     Id = c.FirstOrDefault().tblCategoryDetail.tblCategory.Category_Id,
                     categoryIcon = c.FirstOrDefault().tblCategoryDetail.tblCategory.Category_Icon
                 });
            ViewBag.time = DateTime.Now;
            return View(obj.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: How are you testing it? I hope not through IIS Express and Visual Studio?

Comment: no im test it in Server and IIS 7.0

Comment: so, after 1 minute if you request the page,  it will execute index action? but if you request before 1minute you get the cached page?

Comment: try add this line `<clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />` to `web.config` please , did it solve the problem?

Comment: dear Sepehr , Is already set and not curect